Gravitational Wave Impact on Connected Particles
We understand that when a gravitational wave passes through a setup with two freely falling particles, it causes them to oscillate and change the distance between them. However, if the two particles are connected by a massless rod, we wonder if the gravitational wave would affect the length of the rod in the same way. Is there a distinction between these two scenarios?

Do you see this different from the question what the ground below your feet does to you?

Why do you think this would be any different? The length of the arms of the LIGO interferometer change when a gravitational wave passes. That is how we verified they exist.

If the rod in the setup experiences the same length change, it would render gravitational wave detection impossible. Here’s why: When any local length changes uniformly (multiplied by the same factor), using a ruler (including light wavelength), you perceive no difference because the ruler itself is scaled by the same factor.

Our gravitational wave detector, LIGO, is actually a stopwatch and not a ruler.

Veritasium made a video on how difficult it is to detect gravitational waves. The Absurdity of Detecting Gravitational Waves. He discusses your question at around 5:30.

Also see Is LIGO flawed by the identical expansion of laser wavelength and arms in presence of a gravitational wave?
